# issue with anyType in webservice consumer transformation in powercentre

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a wsdl with anyType as given below

```
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="value" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

the request generated by web service consumer transformation is as below.

```
<dynamics>
  <entry>
   <key>?</key>
   <value>?</value>
  </entry>
</dynamics>
```

But with this request the API throws an error

```
<faultstring>Whole Number text field [xxxxxx] type [xxxx] is not String. 
</faultstring>
```

I tried sending the same request in SOAP UI and it throws the same error.

However, when we i make minor change by adding name space s and execute the same in SOAP UI, it is returning success

```
<dynamics>
  <entry>
    <key>?</key>
    <value xsi:type="xs:string"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">?</value>
  </entry>
</dynamics>
```

How can i add this extra name space information in web service consumer mapping?

Is there a way to handle this?

Also please note that we are trying to connect to API using http cookie. hence not sure if we can use http transformation or java tranformation in this case.

experts Please help.

Comment: can you share what exactly you changed? is it just adding a space into the value ?

Comment: Iam adding namespace string to the value tag. xsi:type="xs:string"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

Answer (score 0):

used http transformation with simple post method to pass the customised SOAP request.

Thanks